# Cross-platform compiling with Visual Studio Projects files

Tags: c++, build-process, build-automation, cross-compiling

I have Visual Studio projects that I would like to compile on Linux and MAC.

I start looking for cross-platform build systems. Most of them require to write a build script from scratch. Others generate projects files... The problem is that I feel more confortable with editing vcproj files instead of associated build scripts.

**Is there any tool that could take a vcproj files as input to perform cross-platform compilation on Linux and MAC?**

Best regards.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: could you elaborate a bit please? Premake seems great indeed. What is the initial workflow and the daily worflow with Premake (see my comment for details). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) files to build the project. This will allow you greater control over the compilation process, and this is a requirement to build cross-platform solutions.

CMake is very used and well documented.

Comment: thanks. This is what I wanted to avoid actually. But if by experience you believe this is the best solution, then we will try it. Could you please add in your answer the initial workflow (basic steps to get running) and the daily workflow (what should we do when programming on VS, changing properties, and recompile everything on every needed platforms) please?